# Python While loop not executing as expected

Tags: python, email, while-loop, outlook, win32com

I'm trying to create a means of archiving my inbox in Python. What I would like to have happen is for the code to iterate through all emails in a particular folder within my Outlook inbox, and check to see if they have already been completed. The check for whether they are 'completed' or not will be based on the 'TaskCompletedDate' associated with the particular email. If the 'TaskCompletedDate' for the particular email is a certain value that would indicate it has not yet been completed, it will leave that email as-is and move on to the next email. If it runs into an email where the 'TaskCompletedDate' is a certain value that would indicate is has already been completed, it will move the email to an archive folder.

The following is what I've written to test it before moving any actual emails in order to make sure it will work. In the below code, I am creating a list (in this case, called 'a') of each email's Subject line, and then attempting to use a While loop to iterate through each email and check what the 'TaskCompletedDate' associated with it is. If it passes the If condition within that While loop (in this case representing an email which has not yet been completed, and should be left as-is), it will move to the next index number and continue. If it reaches an index where that particular email's associated 'TaskCompletedDate' does not satisfy the If condition, it will remove the entry associated with that index from the list ('a'). In the real scenario, emails would be getting removed from the folder as they are archived, which would presumably mean the indices of each email would be changing as a result. Because of this, I've also included a clause to reduce the range length (representing the total number of emails in the folder) by 1 each time an entry is removed from the list (or archived, in the real-world scenario).

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
folder = outlook.Folders.Item("Example@Example.com")
inbox = folder.Folders.Item("Inbox")
msg = inbox.Items

a=[]
for i in range(len(msg)):    
    a.append(msg[i].Subject)

aLen = len(a)
i = 0

while i < aLen:
    if str(msg[i].TaskCompletedDate)[0:4] != '2020':
        i += 1
    else:
        del a[i]
        aLen = aLen - 1
```

The desired end-state of the list would be that it would only contain Subject lines of emails which satisfied the If condition within the While loop (representing emails which were not archived), and all Subject lines of emails which did not satisfy the If condition, would be removed from the list (representing emails which were archived and removed from the inbox).

The issue that I'm running into is that the end-state seems to come up with an empty list, and I'm not entirely sure why. There are certainly emails which satisfy the If condition within the folder, so those should not be being removed from the list, if I understand correctly.

Any help or thoughts would be most appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: As soon as you find a message without ‘2020’ in it, you delete it from ‘a’, but next time round the loop, you are looking at the same value from ‘msg’. You should look into creating ‘a’ from a list comprehension which includes an if clause.

Answer (score 1):

When you decrement `aLen` so as to avoid an index out of range error, there is a possibility (if even one value doesn't meet your condition) you do not iterate fully over `msg`. Depending on how the items are ordered, this could be causing your issue. I would also check, for sanity, that `msg` is non empty.

If you need or feel so inclined as to keep your loop, I would suggest **only appending items that *do* meet the condition**. From a storage optimization and best practice perspective, this is cleaner and more efficient than populating `a` with all possible items and deleting ones that don't match the condition. Thus, I would replace your for and while loops with:

```
a=[]
for x in msg:
   if str(x.TaskCompletedDate)[0:4] != '2020':
      a.append(x.Subject)
```

Otherwise, a far more efficient way of populating `a` would be:

```
a = [x.Subject for x in msg if str(x.TaskCompletedDate)[0:4] != '2020']
```

As a final note I would suggest reading up on for loops and where to use while loops vs where to use for loops as some of your syntax can be simplified and cleaned up a little bit.
Here are a few good links to parts of the Python docs:
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Hope this helps :)